# JMS Connection to Websphere Server

Tags: java, jms, websphere

I am currently trying to create a JMS Queue to a Web Sphere server, Now i have followed all the tutorials on-line and have reached a wall. I have set up the server and my test application and can not seem to get it to connect. This is the output i get when i try to connect, was hopping someone on here has the knowledge to help me fix this problem as its driving me crazy

This is the output i get when i try to connect:

```
Exception in thread "P=848735:O=0:CT" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.ffdc.Manager
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.RasUtil.logException(RasUtil.java:164)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.RasUtil.logException(RasUtil.java:72)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.getOrb(Helpers.java:398)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getInitialContextInternal(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:462)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContext(WsnInitCtx.java:128)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContextIfNull(WsnInitCtx.java:765)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:164)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436)
    at message.JMSMessageSender.connect(JMSMessageSender.java:68)
    at client.JMSTester.main(JMSTester.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.ffdc.Manager
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:688)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:667)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:650)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: "NoClassDefFoundError" Did you install the necessary libraries?

Answer (score 2):

A quote from a possibly related [IBM technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21358301)

> Add the WebSphere Application Server Administration Thin Client JAR jar
>
> com.ibm.ws.admin.client_X.0.0.jar
>
> to the application Java Build Path located in the runtimes folder of the WebSphere Application Server installation directory.

Note that the technote is not special for JMS. But possibly in your case the JMS libraries introduce a dependency on FFDC as well.